# Writing data to a .CSV file using a Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, collections, java-stream, filewriter

I am trying to output 2 collections of data to a .csv file in Java.

Collection 1 = customer names
Collection 2 = customer references

I want the .csv to present as:

```
Smith:839393,
Johnson:283940,
Collins:293845
```

My code:

```
private void writeDataToFile() throws IOException {

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("src/test/resources/custData.csv");

    List<String> customers = new ArrayList<>(customers);
    List<String> references = new ArrayList<>(references);

    String collect1 = customers.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",\n" + ":"));
    String collect2 = references.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",\n" + ":"));

    writer.write(collect1 + collect2);
    writer.close();

}
```

My output:

```
Smith,
:Johnson,
:Collins839393,
:283940,
:293845
```

How can I achieve the desired output?

Comment: You are probably missing an abstraction that contains the `customer` with a `reference`.

Comment: By the way, those colon characters violate [CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way if both lists have the same size. Use `IntStream.range` to iterate the lists and then map the data. Then collect joining `,\n`

```
String res = IntStream.range(0, customers.size())
                      .mapToObj(i -> customers.get(i) + ":" + references.get(i))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming both of your collections have same number of elements you can try this

```
String output =
        IntStream.rangeClosed(0, customers.size()-1)
            .boxed()
            .map(i -> customers.get(i) + ":" + references.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
writer.write(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume `customers` and `references` have the same size. You can iterate between 0 and `customers.size()` and combine the elements of both lists:

```
customers.get(i) + ":" + references.get(i) + ",\n"
```

Try this:

```
String output = IntStream.range(0, customers.size()).boxed()
        .map(i -> customers.get(i) + ":" + references.get(i) + ",\n").collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is called collection zipping.

See [full article here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collections-zip)

In pure java you can do the solutions

```
IntStream.range(0, Math.min(customers.size(), references.size()))
         .mapToObj(i -> customers.get(i) + ":" + references.get(i))
         .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"));
```

If you have guava you can do it bit nicer

```
Streams
    .zip(customers.stream(), references.stream(), (customer, reference) -> customer + ":" + reference)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(",\n"));
```